# CakePHP - FormHelper and a DATETIME field UI

Tags: cakephp, user-interface

CakePHP FormHelper very helpfully sets up a number of select boxes for the DATETIME fields in an input form, making it possible to choose a precise DATETIME. But, it doesn't really do it for me in terms of quality User Interface.

Is there a way to make this look more pretty and easy to operate? Instead of choosing 5 select fields? Maybe something like a built in time-picker tool or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `'type' => 'text'` to the input and then add any javascript date picker you like. There are literally hundreds on google. Quick search and you should have one in no time at all.

Comment: In the end I opted for the Trent Richardsson [plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).